# custom range on second y axis in ggplot (have already performed transformation)

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I am familiar with transforming my secondary y axis values in ggplot, however, I am unable to set a custom range for the min and max values. I would ultimately like to set the second y axis range values to a min of 40 and a max of 80. my first y variable has a range (0,108) and my second y variable has a range (47.44 - 71.17). In plot 1 we have a one to one transformation where I have the range going from a min of 0 to a max of 90. the code to produce this is

```
geom_line(aes(x=DATE, y = value/.75,colour= variable), size= 2)
```

and subsequently

```
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),
                     breaks = seq(0,120, by = 20),
                     label = comma,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*.75,
                                         breaks= seq(0,90,by=10),
                                         name = "Temperature (°F)"),
                     limits = c(0,120))
```

[transformed second axes min 0 max 90](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtvOZ.jpg)

I have also tried this script to no avail

```
geom_line(aes(x=DATE, y = (value-40)/.75,colour= variable), size= 2)
```

and subsequently

```
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),
                     breaks = seq(0,120, by = 20),
                     label = comma,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*.75+40,
                                         breaks= seq(40,80,by=10),
                                         name = "Temperature (°F)"),
                     limits = c(0,120))
```

which produces plot 2

[transformed second axes min 40 to max 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMAyp.jpg)

thanks in advance for any help with this

Answer (score 0):

For future questions, please include something like this to reduce ambiguity and duplication of effort.

[How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

```
set.seed(0)
my_data <- tibble(DATE = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-1-31"), by = "day"),
                  var1 = rpois(31, 5)^2,
                  var2 = runif(31, 40, 80))
```

Without transformation, this produces something like your example:

```
ggplot(my_data) +
  geom_col(aes(DATE, var1), fill = "gray70") +
  geom_line(aes(DATE, var2))

range(my_data$var1)  # 1 to 121
range(my_data$var2)  # 41 to 77
```

[image]

Let's say we want the 2nd axis to take up the whole scale range,
so ~40 becomes 0 and ~80 becomes 120.

(var2 range - 40) * 3 = var1 range

We'll want to do the opposite translation for the axis itself:

(var2 scale / 3) + 40 = var1 scale

```
# transformed
ggplot(my_data) +
  geom_col(aes(DATE, var1), fill = "gray70") +
  geom_line(aes(DATE, (var2-40)*3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = ~(./3)+40)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jon - had my signs switched in the notation and lacked the closure. Much appreciated, and thanks for all you do. Similar examples do not get to the answer like this one does.